# How to prevent MongoDB from printing cluster update logs to console?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

How to stop printing the below logs which is coming in every seconds? I am using `Spring MVC+ Spring Data Mongo + Java 8`

```
21:45:31.697 [cluster-ClusterId{value='56718e190dc287176059194e', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Checking status of localhost:27017
21:45:31.699 [cluster-ClusterId{value='56718e190dc287176059194e', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=0.7 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
```

I am using the following dependencies.

```
<spring-data-mongodb-version>1.8.1.RELEASE</spring-data-mongodb-version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-mongodb-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You could turn OFF the logger for org.mongodb.driver.cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these few lines

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;


static Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);

    static {
        root.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    }
```